# How do I load a numpy file into a google colab/ jupyter notebook correctly?

Tags: numpy

I am using this code:

```
data = np.load('images.npy')
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2bb4bd12d191> in <module>()
----> 1 data = np.load('images.npy')

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py in read_array(fp, allow_pickle, pickle_kwargs)
    785             array = array.transpose()
    786         else:
--> 787             array.shape = shape
    788 
    789     return array

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 30408576 into shape (4981,256,256,3)
```

A friend of mine used the exact same code and it worked for him, what could I try in order to fix this?

Comment: The file might be corrupted. Could you try uploading it and then trying it again?

Comment: For some reason it could only a fraction of the whole file - may be because it was downloaded in full.